# Getting rid of duplicate subqueries in UNION in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, union

I generated a football standings and there's a huge duplicated part that I want to get rid of. I have the following tables:

```
match (matchID, homeTeamID, visitingTeamID)
goals (matchID, playerID, isOwnGoal)
```

I'm counting the goals for each match in the goals table and joining them in the match table in a SELECT statement (Let's call it MatchWithScoresTable). In the subquery, I use two SELECT statements to count the scores of the teams in matches  of both home and away and UNION them in one.

The problem is that these two SELECT statements both SELECT from the exactly same subquery (MatchWithScores).

Here's the structure of the query to give you an idea:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM( 
    SELECT  
        ...
    FROM (
        SELECT ...  -- MatchWithScores
    ) AS HOME

  UNION ALL 

    SELECT  
        ... 
    FROM (
        SELECT ...  -- MatchWithScores
    ) AS VISITING
)
```

I'm relatively new to constructing such complicated queries and I hope I could explain well enough what the problem is. Is there a way to eliminate this duplication without storing the calculated match scores from goals in the match table?

Note: My DBMS is SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE:

```
with MatchWithScores as (
      select . . .
     )
select . . .
from ((select . . . from MatchWithScores)
      union all
      (select . . . from MatchWithScores)
     ) hv
```